# Upload Doesn't Work

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to upload an imgage and save its path in my database but it does not work.

Here is my HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/from-data">
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
        <input type="text" name="titrel" value="<?php echo $result->titrel; ?>" placeholder="Titre long:" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input type="text" name="titrec" value="<?php echo $result->titrec; ?>" placeholder="Titre cour:" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $result->description; ?>" placeholder="Description:" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input type="text" name="histo" value="<?php echo $result->histo; ?>" placeholder="histo:" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="12345" />
        <input type="file" name="images" value="<?php echo $result->images; ?>" placeholder="Images:" />
      </div>
      <br />
       <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input type="date" name="datepub" value="<?php echo $result->datepub; ?>" placeholder="datepub:" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="edition" class="btn btn-primary" value="edition data">          
    </form>
```

and my PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['creer'])){

    $titrel  = $_POST['titrel'];
    $titrec = $_POST['titrec'];
    $description  = $_POST['description'];
    $histo = $_POST['histo'];
    $datepub = $_POST['datepub'];
    $images  = $_FILES['images'];
    $images=   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], './upload/'.$_FILES['images']['name']);
    $sql  = 'INSERT INTO ouvrage (titrel,titrec,description,histo,datepub,images) ';
    $sql .= 'VALUES (:titrel, :titrec, :description, :histo, :datepub, :images)';

    try {
      $create = $db->prepare($sql);
      $create->bindValue(':titrel', $titrel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $create->bindValue(':titrec', $titrec, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $create->bindValue(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $create->bindValue(':histo', $histo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $create->bindValue(':datepub', $datepub, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $create->bindValue(':images', $images, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      if($create->execute()){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
        <strong>Inserido com sucesso!</strong>
        </div>";
      }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
        <strong>Erro ao inserir dados!</strong>" . $e->getMessage() . "
        </div>";
    }

  }
```

I dont work update  I recovered / upload my db but not the file name and  i have error notice undefined  index line 45 and 46

Comment: You have a typo in `enctype="multipart/from-data"` where it should read as `enctype="multipart/form-data"` - Fix that, if that's your actual code.

Comment: Plus, you don't have a form element named/called `creer` which your entire script is dependant on `if(isset($_POST['creer']))`

Comment: ...try changing that to `if(isset($_POST['edition']))` instead, along with my other recommendation.

Comment: hi fred-ii, i fix enctyp and post error when copying my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

> Returns TRUE on success.

```
$images=   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], './upload/'.$_FILES['images']['name']);
$create->bindValue(':images', $images, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

so yeah, this won't save any path in your database

along with fixing what @Fred notes in the comments (if we were in the nhl, he'd deserve an assist), you can do this on two lines:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], './upload/'.$_FILES['images']['name']);
$images= './upload/'.$_FILES['images']['name'];
```

you can even wrap your try/catch block to only be executed if the server successfully moved the image

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], './upload/'.$_FILES['images']['name']))
 {$images= './upload/'.$_FILES['images']['name'];
  // the rest of your code from $sql= [...]
  }
```

Comment: how I should proceed to save the path of my image?

Comment: @tycoons this could help you, take a look

Comment: how I recovered the path for example if I want to change in a update thank you for you help

Comment: the update routine will be the same as the original insert. you do know how `UPDATE ... WHERE ...` works in mysql, right? upload forms can never know which file was uploaded on the client machine, meaning updating a path is always like overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for the mention. Go "HABS"? Nordique? ;-) cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- je suis pas mal pour le Canadien..

Comment: Moi aussi. Mon hero etait Jean Beliveau #4, donc tu vois que je ne suis pas aussi jeune que tu crois peut-etre le penser ;-)